# How to ignore events in Observable if condition does not match?

Tags: observable, rxjs6

I want to place a condition such that I want to ignore the action event if the condition is not met in the nested pipe condition.

If I just return `ignoreElements` it is causing an error that the return value does not stream.

```
export const getDataEpic: (action$, state$,
    { apolloClient, services }: { apolloClient: ApolloClient<any>, services: any }) => any
    = (action$, state$, { apolloClient, services }) =>
        action$.pipe(ofType('TEST)).pipe(map(x => x))
            .pipe(
                switchMap((action) =>
                    of([true, false, true]))
                        .pipe(
                            map(settings => ({ action, config: settings})), // true or false
                            switchMap(value=> {
                                if(value.config)
                                  return of([1])
                                } else {
                                   // if condition not met then don't emit anything
                                    return ignoreElements();
                                }
                            }),
                        ),

                ),
                groupBy(value => value.action.payload.model.resource),
                mergeMap(ngroup => ngroup
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you're returning an *operator function* instead of an observable. You should return `EMPTY` if you need an observable that emits no items.

```js
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs'

...
switchMap(value => {
  if (value.config)
    return of([1])
  } else {
    // if condition not met then don't emit anything
    return EMPTY
  }
})
...
```

Comment: aah... got it. Let me test it.